# ASP.NET MVC client validation from Service Layer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, model-view-controller, service-layer

I'm following this article

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-(data)/validating-with-a-service-layer-cs

to include a Service Layer with Business Logic in my ASP.NET MVC Web Application.

I'm able to pass messages from the Service Layer to the View Model in a `Html.ValidationSummary` using `ModelState` class.

I perform basic validation logic on the View Model (using `DataAnnotation` attributes) and I have `ClientValidation` enabled by default, which displaying the error message on **every single field of my form**.

The Business logic error message which come from the Service Layer are being displayed on `Html.ValidationSummary` only after Posting the form to the Server.

After Validation from the Service Layer, I would like highlight one or more fields and have the message from the Service Layer showing on these fields instead that the `Html.ValidationSummary`.

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how the validation looks on the server:

```
protected bool ValidateProduct(Product productToValidate)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(productToValidate.Name))
        _validatonDictionary.AddError("Name", "Name is required.");
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(productToValidate.Description))
        _validatonDictionary.AddError("Description", "Description is required.");
    if (productToValidate.UnitsInStock < 0)
        _validatonDictionary.AddError("UnitsInStock", "Units in stock cannot be less than zero.");
    return _validatonDictionary.IsValid;
}
```

All you have to do is to have corresponding `ValidationMessageFor` helpers for those fields in the view and the error message coming from the server will be associated to the corresponding field:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Description)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Description)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Description)
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Create</button>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Darin I found out the solution to my problems.

In details:

I can use

```
 _validatonDictionary.AddError("Name of my field", "Custom message")
```

so I can show a message and highlight that specific field (very simple to do with DataAnnotation).

In case I want display just a message in ValidationSummary without highlight a specific field I use

```
_validatonDictionary.AddError(string.Empty, "Custom message")
```

Please note the `string.Empty`